# Weighted Average calculation based on conditions in pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 `dataframes` for `Promotion Data`  and `Sales Data` as below.

```
+-----------+----------+
| Promotion |   Date   |
+-----------+----------+
|     A     | 5-Jan-21 |
+-----------+----------+
|     B     | 8-Jan-21 |
+-----------+----------+
|     C     | 8-Jan-21 |
+-----------+----------+

df_prom = pd.DataFrame({
    'Promotion':['A','B','C'],
    'Date':['5-Jan-21','8-Jan-21','8-Jan-21']  })

+-----------+-------+
|    Date   | Sales |
+-----------+-------+
|  1-Jan-21 | 1,140 |
+-----------+-------+
|  2-Jan-21 | 3,046 |
+-----------+-------+
|  3-Jan-21 | 2,981 |
+-----------+-------+
|  4-Jan-21 | 2,262 |
+-----------+-------+
|  5-Jan-21 | 3,266 |
+-----------+-------+
|  6-Jan-21 | 3,231 |
+-----------+-------+
|  7-Jan-21 | 2,979 |
+-----------+-------+
|  8-Jan-21 | 1,687 |
+-----------+-------+
|  9-Jan-21 | 2,728 |
+-----------+-------+
| 10-Jan-21 | 1,136 |
+-----------+-------+
| 11-Jan-21 | 3,159 |
+-----------+-------+
| 12-Jan-21 | 1,799 |
+-----------+-------+

    df_sales = pd.DataFrame({
        'Date':['1-Jan-21', '2-Jan-21', '3-Jan-21', '4-Jan-21', '5-Jan-21', '6-Jan-21', '7-Jan-21',
 '8-Jan-21', '9-Jan-21', '10-Jan-21', '11-Jan-21', '12-Jan-21'],
        'Sales':[1140, 3046, 2981, 2262, 3266, 3231, 2979, 1687, 2728, 1136, 3159, 1799]
    })
```

My task is to calculate a `weighted average` `Prior 3 days` & `Post 3 days sales` considering all 3 promotions.

Meaning, All 3 promotions has different dates. I need to bring it to a common `Prior 3 days` & common `Post 3 days`.

Step 1:

Eg `Promotion A` is on `5-Jan-21`, so `Prior 3 days` would be from `2-Jan-21 to 4-Jan-21`.

so the average would be `2763` (average of 3046, 2981, 2262)
that of `Post 3 Days` would be `6-Jan-21 to 8-Jan-21`.so the average would be `2632` (average of 3231, 2979, 1687)

in the case of `Promotion B` is on `8-Jan-21`, `Prior 3 days` would be `5-Jan-21 to 7-Jan-21` averages is equal to `3159` (average of 3266, 3231, 2979).

The `Post 3 days` would be `9-Jan-21 to 11-Jan-21` average is `2341` (average of 2728, 1136, 3159).

For `C` it is same as `B`. since, the dates are same.

Step 2:

Once after calculating the `Prior 3` of `A, B and C` individually. I must averages this together. i.e average would be `3027` (Average of 2763 of `A`, 3159 of `B` and  3159 of `C`).
same applied to `Post 3 days` average. which is equal to `2438` (Average of 2632 of `A`,  2341 of `B`  and 2341 of `C`).

so my final answer should look like

```
+--------------+---------+
| Type         | Average |
+--------------+---------+
| Prior 3 days | 3,027   |
+--------------+---------+
| Post 3 days  | 2,438   |
+--------------+---------+
```

please guide me on how should I approach to solve this.

Comment: I think the best is add this overlapping dates to sample data.

Comment: ok. let me change the sample data to accommodate overlapping dates

Comment: There is always consecutive datetimes?

Comment: sorry. I didn't get your question?

Comment: If in `df_sales` are datetimes consecutive

Comment: I can sort it by date before processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution working with overlapping values, because each datetime is processing separately.

For correct working is necessary all datetimes before and after 3 values exist in `df_sales['Date']` and are sorted.

First convert values to datetimes:

```
df_prom['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_prom['Date'], format='%d-%b-%y')
df_sales['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_sales['Date'], format='%d-%b-%y')
```

Then repeat `Date` column to DataFrame with number of columns like values in `df_prom`:

```
arr = np.broadcast_to(df_sales['Date'].to_numpy()[:, None],
                     (df_sales.shape[0], df_prom.shape[0]))

df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
```

Compare datetimes and forward 3 and back filling 3 values for 3 previous and 3 next datetimes, this mask is used for filter `Sales`:

```
m = df.eq(df_prom['Date'])
prev_mask = df.where(m).bfill(limit=3).mask(m).notna()
next_mask = df.where(m).ffill(limit=3).mask(m).notna()

prev = np.where(prev_mask, df_sales['Sales'].to_numpy()[:, None], np.nan)
next1 = np.where(next_mask, df_sales['Sales'].to_numpy()[:, None], np.nan)
```

---

```
print (prev)
[[  nan   nan   nan]
 [3046.   nan   nan]
 [2981.   nan   nan]
 [2262.   nan   nan]
 [  nan 3266. 3266.]
 [  nan 3231. 3231.]
 [  nan 2979. 2979.]
 [  nan   nan   nan]
 [  nan   nan   nan]
 [  nan   nan   nan]
 [  nan   nan   nan]
 [  nan   nan   nan]]
print (next1)
[[  nan   nan   nan]
 [  nan   nan   nan]
 [  nan   nan   nan]
 [  nan   nan   nan]
 [  nan   nan   nan]
 [3231.   nan   nan]
 [2979.   nan   nan]
 [1687.   nan   nan]
 [  nan 2728. 2728.]
 [  nan 1136. 1136.]
 [  nan 3159. 3159.]
 [  nan   nan   nan]]
```

And last get mean with omit missing values:

```
fin = pd.DataFrame({'Type':['Prior 3 days','Post 3 days'],
                    'Average':[np.nanmean(prev), np.nanmean(next1)]
                    })
print (fin)
           Type      Average
0  Prior 3 days  3026.777778
1   Post 3 days  2438.111111
```

EDIT:

For dynamic limits use:

```
limits = (pd.to_datetime('12-Jan-2021') - df_prom['Date']).dt.days

d = dict(enumerate(limits))
print (d)

prev_mask = df.where(m).apply(lambda x: x.bfill(limit=d[x.name])).mask(m).notna()
next_mask = df.where(m).apply(lambda x: x.ffill(limit=d[x.name])).mask(m).notna()
```

---

```
print (prev)
[[1140.   nan   nan]
 [3046.   nan   nan]
 [2981.   nan   nan]
 [2262. 2262. 2262.]
 [  nan 3266. 3266.]
 [  nan 3231. 3231.]
 [  nan 2979. 2979.]
 [  nan   nan   nan]
 [  nan   nan   nan]
 [  nan   nan   nan]
 [  nan   nan   nan]
 [  nan   nan   nan]]

print (next1)
[[  nan   nan   nan]
 [  nan   nan   nan]
 [  nan   nan   nan]
 [  nan   nan   nan]
 [  nan   nan   nan]
 [3231.   nan   nan]
 [2979.   nan   nan]
 [1687.   nan   nan]
 [2728. 2728. 2728.]
 [1136. 1136. 1136.]
 [3159. 3159. 3159.]
 [1799. 1799. 1799.]]
```

Comment: Great. this works with overlapping dates as well

Comment: if I want to change the limit in `next_mask` from `3` to `end of 12-Jan-21`. meaning variable limits. for `A its 7` and for `B and C its 4`. I tried to calculate the `time delta`, since its' a `Series` not an `int`. it throws an error. what should be the recommended way?

Comment: calculated `limits=  pd.to_datetime('12-Jan-2021') - df_prom['Date']`  and converted to days only `limits = limits.dt.days`. Then replaced `3` with `limits`. throws an error since it is a `Series`

Comment: @Tommy - More complicated, because it means you need change `limit=3` dynamic, understand correct?

Comment: correct. more dynamic with single cut-off date. eg `until end of 12-Jan-21` for all the `promotions A,B and C`

Comment: @Tommy - Answer was edited, only mask part.

Comment: this is great. however, I'm not getting the right answer when I calculate it manually.  eg answer for the `Post 3` is `2266 (avg of 2388 A, 2206 B, 2206 C)`. But the above code gives me `2291`

Comment: @Tommy - Yes, because there is not `7` days before in sample data, only 4 days. So it count means for `A` for 4 values before.

Comment: @Tommy - If check in my sample data `print (prev)` and `print (next1)` are data correct used for mean?

Comment: OK. what I did. I left the `prev_mask` unchanged. as the limit of this will always be `3`. w.r.t `Post`, we have `7 days for A` and `4 days for the rest.` so, When I calculate this Post manually (per above comment), the answer differs.

Comment: @Tommy - Added to answer `prev` and `next1` ouputs, first column is for `A` (7), second for `B` (4) and last for `C` (4). Is ouput correct?

Comment: Yes. the `next1` output is correct. If we `mean` across, we should get `2388-A, 2206-B and 2206-C`. finally `mean` of these `3` should be `2266`.

Comment: `[2388.42857143  2205.5        2205.5       ]` this is correct. But, I'm not sure how we get `2290.866666666667`..

Comment: @Tommy - I see. It depends what need. If use `np.nanmean(next1)` it means get all data from `next1` and return mean. You maybe need first means per columns and then another mean. It return something different, because `mean` of `mean` return different like `sum` of `sum`

Comment: @Tommy - It meand for `next1` is used `([3231.0+ 2979.0+ 1687.0+ 2728.0+ 2728.0+ 2728.0+ 1136.0+ 1136.0+ 1136.0+3159.0+ 3159.0+ 3159.0+ 1799.0+ 1799.0+ 1799.0) / 15`

Comment: @Tommy - `(3231.0+ 2979.0+ 1687.0+ 2728.0+ 2728.0+ 2728.0+ 1136.0+ 1136.0+ 1136.0+3159.0+ 3159.0+ 3159.0+ 1799.0+ 1799.0+ 1799.0) / 15 = 2290.866666666667`

Comment: oh. I get it now. where should I modify to get the answer of `mean = 2266`?

Comment: @Tommy - Then use `np.nanmean(next1, axis=0).mean()`

Answer (score 2):

Sample Data:

```
df_sales = pd.DataFrame({
        'Date':['1-Jan-21', '2-Jan-21', '3-Jan-21', '4-Jan-21', '5-Jan-21', '6-Jan-21', '7-Jan-21',
 '8-Jan-21', '9-Jan-21', '10-Jan-21', '11-Jan-21', '12-Jan-21'],
        'Sales':[1140, 3046, 2981, 2262, 3266, 3231, 2979, 1687, 2728, 1136, 3159, 1799]
    })

df_prom = pd.DataFrame({
    'Promotion':['A','B', 'C'],
    'Date':['5-Jan-21','8-Jan-21', '8-Jan-21']  })
```

Steps:

```
df_proms = df_prom.groupby('Date').count().reset_index()

df = df_sales.merge(df_proms, on='Date', how='left')

df['rolling'] = df['Sales'].rolling(3).mean()

df['post 3 days'] = df['rolling'].shift(-3) * df['Promotion']
df['prior 3 days'] = df['rolling'].shift(1) * df['Promotion']

df = df[~df.Promotion.isnull()]

weighted_df = pd.DataFrame(data=df[['post 3 days', 'prior 3 days']].sum()/df['Promotion'].sum()).reset_index().rename({"index": "Type", 0: "Average"}, axis=1)

weighted_df
    Type    Average
0   post 3 days     2438.111111
1   prior 3 days    3026.777778
```

Comment: In my opinion answer working only if not overlapping values, is possible create overlapping dates and prove your solution is correct? Like `C 8-Jan-20`, `D 8-Jan-21`. also missing descrption

Comment: ok. let me change the sample data to accommodate overlapping dates

Comment: Upvoted. Now it works with the given overlapping example.

Comment: Much better, only one thing, working with partly overlapping? `D 8-Jan-21` ?